# Hair look different between the viewport and the rendering, why?

Tags: rendering, particles, hair

[image]

The hair of my character is completely buggy when I render it (while normal in the viewport).

-it's a hair particle system rather simple

-I use the same display amount / render amount (100)

-The rendering picture is made with EEVEE and it does the same in Cycles.

It feels like the weight painting is replaced with random bugs.

Anyone has an idea about that?

thanks

Comment: Probably you have a subdivision surface modifier with a differenet amount on viewport and render. Adjust it to the same for render as viewport.

Comment: Oh thanks! It's exactly what was wrong